# Kivymd: Can not add multiple textfield and buttons in Scrollview

Tags: python, kivy, scrollview, kivymd

I was trying to add many textfields and buttons in a screen with a scroll view so that I can scroll up and down. But the positions and size are not showing in corresponding place.

Here is my problem demo script:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder

KV = """ 
Screen:
    MDToolbar:
        title:'Mini Agriculturist'
        pos_hint:{'top':1}
        left_action_items : [["arrow-left"]]
        right_action_items : [["dots-vertical"]]
        elevation:15

    ScrollView:
        pos_hint:{'top':0.88}
        # size_hint_y:0.7
        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            size_hint_y: None
            # orientation:'vertical'
            spacing:'10dp'
            MDTextField:
                hint_text: "Category"
                mode: "rectangle"
                size_hint_x:0.4
                pos_hint_x:0.5
                multiple_line: True
                id: Test_ss
            MDTextField:
                hint_text: "Disease name"
                mode: "rectangle"  
                size_hint_x:0.4
                pos_hint_x:0.5 
            MDTextField:
                hint_text: "Symptoms"
                mode: "rectangle"
                size_hint_x:0.4
                pos_hint_x:0.5 
                multiple_line: True  
            MDTextField:
                hint_text: "More about disease"
                mode: "rectangle" 
                size_hint_x:0.4
                pos_hint_x:0.5  
                multiple_line: True  
            MDTextField:
                hint_text: "Category"
                mode: "rectangle" 
                size_hint_x:0.4
                pos_hint_x:0.5 
                multiple_line: True
            MDTextField:
                hint_text: "Disease name"
                mode: "rectangle"  
                size_hint_x:0.4
                pos_hint_x:0.5 
                multiple_line: True
            MDTextField:
                hint_text: "Symptoms"
                mode: "rectangle"
                size_hint_x:0.4
                pos_hint_x:0.5  
                multiple_line: True 
            MDTextField:
                hint_text: "More about disease"
                mode: "rectangle" 
                size_hint_x:0.4
                pos_hint_x:0.5
            MDTextField:
                hint_text: "Disease name"
                mode: "rectangle"  
                size_hint_x:0.4
                pos_hint_x:0.5 
            MDTextField:
                hint_text: "Symptoms"
                mode: "rectangle"
                size_hint_x:0.4
                pos_hint_x:0.5   
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text:'Choose'
                font_size:14
                halign: "center"  
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text:'Cancel'
                font_size:14
                halign: "center"

"""

class WeatherApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        pass
    def on_start(self):

        self.root.ids.Test_ss.text = " Dhur bal\nOi salar putera\nMod khaba naki "
    def build(self):
        self.screen = Builder.load_string(KV)
        return self.screen
WeatherApp().run()
```

output Snapshot:
[image]

Problems:

1st, Scrollview not working properly

2nd, can not control the position of componants. Is there any solution?

**I want to create something like this,**
[image]

Can anyone suggest me how can I design the screen like that in image? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This could be helpful:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder

KV = """ 
Screen:
    MDToolbar:
        title:'Contacts jbsidis'
        pos_hint:{'top':1}
        md_bg_color: [.2,0,1,.9]
        left_action_items : [["menu", lambda x:print(23)]]
        right_action_items : [["dots-vertical",lambda x:print(234)]]
        elevation:0

    FloatLayout:
        BoxLayout:
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .38}
            ScrollView:
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: "vertical"
                    spacing: dp(60),dp(100)
                    size_hint_y: .6
                    BoxLayout:
##                MDGridLayout:
##                    cols: 1
##                    row_default_height: (self.width - self.cols*self.spacing[0]) / self.cols
##                    row_force_default: True
##                    adaptive_height: True
##                    padding: dp(10), dp(5)
##                    spacing: dp(8),dp(1)

                    BoxLayout:
                        MDIconButton:
                            #size_hint: .4, .05
                            pos_hint: {"center_x": .3, "top": .975}
                            theme_text_color: "Custom"
                            text_color: [0,0,0,.8]
                            icon: 'account'
                            markup: True
                        TextInput:
                            id: email_jbsidis1
                            height: dp(40)
                            pos_hint: {"center_x": .4, "top": .975}
                            hint_text_color: [0,0,0, 1]
                            foreground_color: [0,0,0,.4]
                            hint_text: "Email"
                            background_color: [1,1,1,0]
                            background_image: ""
                            background_normal: ""
                            background_active: ""
                            multiline: False
                            size_hint: .5 ,None #.06
                            canvas.after:
                                Color:
                                    rgba: [0.0039,0.1921,0.2078,1]
                                Line:
                                    width: dp(0.5)
                                    rounded_rectangle:
                                        (self.x, self.y, self.width-dp(20), dp(43),\
                                        dp(8),dp(8),dp(8),dp(8),\
                                        dp(50))
                    
                    BoxLayout:
                        MDIconButton:
                            #size_hint: .4, .05
                            pos_hint: {"center_x": .3, "top": .975}
                            theme_text_color: "Custom"
                            text_color: [0,0,0,.8]
                            icon: 'phone'
                            markup: True
                        TextInput:
                            id: email_jbsidis2
                            height: dp(40)
                            pos_hint: {"center_x": .4, "top": .975}
                            hint_text_color: [0,0,0, 1]
                            foreground_color: [0,0,0,.4]
                            hint_text: "Phone"
                            background_color: [1,1,1,0]
                            background_image: ""
                            background_normal: ""
                            background_active: ""
                            multiline: False
                            size_hint: .5 ,None #.06
                            canvas.after:
                                Color:
                                    rgba: [0.0039,0.1921,0.2078,1]
                                Line:
                                    width: dp(0.5)
                                    rounded_rectangle:
                                        (self.x, self.y, self.width-dp(20), dp(43),\
                                        dp(8),dp(8),dp(8),dp(8),\
                                        dp(50))
                        TextInput:
                            id: email_jbsidis3
                            height: dp(40)
                            pos_hint: {"center_x": .4, "top": .975}
                            hint_text_color: [0,0,0, 1]
                            foreground_color: [0,0,0,.4]
                            hint_text: "Area"
                            background_color: [1,1,1,0]
                            background_image: ""
                            background_normal: ""
                            background_active: ""
                            multiline: False
                            size_hint: .5 ,None #.06
                            canvas.after:
                                Color:
                                    rgba: [0.0039,0.1921,0.2078,1]
                                Line:
                                    width: dp(0.5)
                                    rounded_rectangle:
                                        (self.x, self.y, self.width-dp(20), dp(43),\
                                        dp(8),dp(8),dp(8),dp(8),\
                                        dp(50))
##                            MDIconButton:
##                                #size_hint: .4, .05
##                                pos_hint: {"center_x": .6, "top": .975}
##                                theme_text_color: "Custom"
##                                text_color: [0,0,0,.8]
##                                icon: 'phone'
##                                markup: True

                    BoxLayout:
                        MDIconButton:
                            #size_hint: .4, .05
                            pos_hint: {"center_x": .3, "top": .975}
                            theme_text_color: "Custom"
                            text_color: [0,0,0,.8]
                            icon: 'map-marker'
                            markup: True
                        TextInput:
                            id: email_jbsidis4
                            height: dp(40)
                            pos_hint: {"center_x": .4, "top": .975}
                            hint_text_color: [0,0,0, 1]
                            foreground_color: [0,0,0,.4]
                            hint_text: "Address"
                            background_color: [1,1,1,0]
                            background_image: ""
                            background_normal: ""
                            background_active: ""
                            multiline: False
                            size_hint: .5 ,None #.06
                            canvas.after:
                                Color:
                                    rgba: [0.0039,0.1921,0.2078,1]
                                Line:
                                    width: dp(0.5)
                                    rounded_rectangle:
                                        (self.x, self.y, self.width-dp(20), dp(43),\
                                        dp(8),dp(8),dp(8),dp(8),\
                                        dp(50))
                    
                    BoxLayout:
                        MDIconButton:
                            #size_hint: .4, .05
                            pos_hint: {"center_x": .3, "top": .975}
                            theme_text_color: "Custom"
                            text_color: [0,0,0,.8]
                            icon: 'a11.png'
                            markup: True
                        TextInput:
                            id: email_jbsidis5
                            height: dp(40)
                            pos_hint: {"center_x": .4, "top": .975}
                            hint_text_color: [0,0,0, 1]
                            foreground_color: [0,0,0,.4]
                            hint_text: "State"
                            background_color: [1,1,1,0]
                            background_image: ""
                            background_normal: ""
                            background_active: ""
                            multiline: False
                            size_hint: .5 ,None #.06
                            canvas.after:
                                Color:
                                    rgba: [0.0039,0.1921,0.2078,1]
                                Line:
                                    width: dp(0.5)
                                    rounded_rectangle:
                                        (self.x, self.y, self.width-dp(20), dp(43),\
                                        dp(8),dp(8),dp(8),dp(8),\
                                        dp(50))
                        TextInput:
                            id: email_jbsidis6
                            height: dp(40)
                            pos_hint: {"center_x": .4, "top": .975}
                            hint_text_color: [0,0,0, 1]
                            foreground_color: [0,0,0,.4]
                            hint_text: "Zipcode"
                            background_color: [1,1,1,0]
                            background_image: ""
                            background_normal: ""
                            background_active: ""
                            multiline: False
                            size_hint: .5 ,None #.06
                            canvas.after:
                                Color:
                                    rgba: [0.0039,0.1921,0.2078,1]
                                Line:
                                    width: dp(0.5)
                                    rounded_rectangle:
                                        (self.x, self.y, self.width-dp(20), dp(43),\
                                        dp(8),dp(8),dp(8),dp(8),\
                                        dp(50))
##                            MDIconButton:
##                                #size_hint: .4, .05
##                                pos_hint: {"center_x": .6, "top": .975}
##                                theme_text_color: "Custom"
##                                text_color: [0,0,0,.8]
##                                icon: 'phone'
##                                markup: True
                    
                    BoxLayout:
                        MDIconButton:
                            #size_hint: .4, .05
                            pos_hint: {"center_x": .3, "top": .975}
                            theme_text_color: "Custom"
                            text_color: [0,0,0,.8]
                            icon: 'message'
                            markup: True
                        TextInput:
                            id: email_jbsidis7
                            height: dp(40)
                            pos_hint: {"center_x": .4, "top": .975}
                            hint_text_color: [0,0,0, 1]
                            foreground_color: [0,0,0,.4]
                            hint_text: "Email"
                            background_color: [1,1,1,0]
                            background_image: ""
                            background_normal: ""
                            background_active: ""
                            multiline: False
                            size_hint: .5 ,None #.06
                            canvas.after:
                                Color:
                                    rgba: [0.0039,0.1921,0.2078,1]
                                Line:
                                    width: dp(0.5)
                                    rounded_rectangle:
                                        (self.x, self.y, self.width-dp(20), dp(43),\
                                        dp(8),dp(8),dp(8),dp(8),\
                                        dp(50))
                    
                    BoxLayout:
                        MDIconButton:
                            #size_hint: .4, .05
                            pos_hint: {"center_x": .3, "top": .975}
                            theme_text_color: "Custom"
                            text_color: [0,0,0,.8]
                            icon: 'calendar'
                            markup: True
                        TextInput:
                            id: email_jbsidis8
                            height: dp(40)
                            pos_hint: {"center_x": .4, "top": .975}
                            hint_text_color: [0,0,0, 1]
                            foreground_color: [0,0,0,.4]
                            hint_text: "Birthday"
                            background_color: [1,1,1,0]
                            background_image: ""
                            background_normal: ""
                            background_active: ""
                            multiline: False
                            size_hint: .5 ,None #.06
                            canvas.after:
                                Color:
                                    rgba: [0.0039,0.1921,0.2078,1]
                                Line:
                                    width: dp(0.5)
                                    rounded_rectangle:
                                        (self.x, self.y, self.width-dp(20), dp(43),\
                                        dp(8),dp(8),dp(8),dp(8),\
                                        dp(50))
##                            FloatLayout:
##                                MDIconButton:
##                                    icon: 'lock-outline'
##                                    markup: True
##                                    opposite_colors: True
##                                    pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.65}   
                    
                    BoxLayout:
                        spacing: dp(30)
                        FloatLayout:
                            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                                pos_hint: {'center_x':.3, 'center_y':.5} 
                                text:'Choose'
                                font_size:14
                                halign: "center"
                                on_release: print(root.ids.email_jbsidis1.text,root.ids.email_jbsidis2.text,root.ids.email_jbsidis3.text,root.ids.email_jbsidis4.text,root.ids.email_jbsidis5.text,root.ids.email_jbsidis6.text,root.ids.email_jbsidis7.text,root.ids.email_jbsidis8.text)
                            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                                pos_hint: {'center_x':.7, 'center_y':.5} 
                                text:'Cancel'
                                font_size:14
                                halign: "center"
                                on_release:
                                    root.ids.email_jbsidis1.text=""
                                    root.ids.email_jbsidis2.text=""
                                    root.ids.email_jbsidis3.text=""
                                    root.ids.email_jbsidis4.text=""
                                    root.ids.email_jbsidis5.text=""
                                    root.ids.email_jbsidis6.text=""
                                    root.ids.email_jbsidis7.text=""
                                    root.ids.email_jbsidis8.text=""
                            

                                        
            
    FloatLayout:
        MDIconButton:
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .8, "center_y": 0.945}
            icon: "magnify"
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: [1,1,1,1]

"""

class WeatherApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        pass
##    def on_start(self):
##
##        self.root.ids.Test_ss.text = " Dhur bal\nOi salar putera\nMod khaba naki "
    def build(self):
        self.screen = Builder.load_string(KV)
        return self.screen
WeatherApp().run()
```

Pictures:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I wanted a scrollable screen with those components.

Comment: You can additional spacing if needed ro separate the widgets, id you've found the answer useful you can upvote the answer.

Comment: I didn't get my actual answer sir, I need a scrollable screen with many textfields, but I cannot do this.

Comment: Alright, the example given above is a screen in which there are many textfields and you can scroll it because it is inside the class ScrollView, you can copy and use that example given in my answer and then you can customize it to your program, once you test the example you will see it scrolls and it has the two buttons below the many textfields, if that's not what was needed then you can edit your question so everybody can provide an appropiate answer

Comment: Would you like to check the result, that what happens when I try your technique (There is also an screenshot)> https://github.com/Shourov1702040/hpylearners_Python/tree/main/Basic%20python/problem

Comment: Thank you for your afford. I have solved it myself.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem with following script

https://github.com/Shourov1702040/hpylearners_Python/blob/main/Basic%20python/Solutions/Many_textfield_with_scrollView.py